# Understanding why the newline is caught on the next iteration

Tags: c

I wrote the following code:

```
int VALUE = 10;
int counter = 0;
char c;
while (true) {
    if(scanf("%c", &c) != 1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    if (counter % VALUE < VALUE - 1) {
        num[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    } else {
        char* temp = (char*) malloc((counter + MAX_VALUE)*sizeof(char));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            temp[i] = num[i];
        }
        free(num);
        num = temp;
        num[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    }
}
printf("counter = %d\n",counter);
```

It doesn't really matter what it does but I have some problem with the `counter`. For some reason, when I insert `9876.54321` (newline at the end), It does not enters into the `if (c == '\n') { break; }` block when it scanfs `\n`, only on the next iteration. The length of `9876.54321` is `10` but it will print `11`. What is the reason? I also tried to switch to `getchar()` but I get the same thing.

Comment: It might be carriage return symbol goes first, as `\r\n`.Try `c == '\n' || c == '\r'`

Comment: @Renat No, it's a `scanf` limitation.

Comment: I tested your code and it gave me 10 when I put 9876.54321 and it does enter into the if (c == '\n') { break; }

Comment: What is`num`? Where/how is it defined?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). The usual way to solve this is to rewrite `scanf("%c", &c)` as `scanf(" %c", &c)` where the added space instructs `scanf` to filter out leading whitespace, if any. Most other format specifiers (`%d`, `%s` etc) do this automatically. It's bad practice to assume that there is always a newline to remove: the newline is not specifically considered or needed by `scanf` and may not always be present.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
if(scanf("%c", &c) != 1) {
```

`%c` in `scanf` leaves the leading and following whitespace in the input buffer.

To fix this, don't use `scanf`. Use `getchar` or `getc` instead. Instead of using `c == '\n'`, use `isspace(c)`.

Don't do `char c`. You can't check for `EOF` if you do that. Instead, use `int c`.

Full code sample:

```
int VALUE = 10;
int counter = 0;
int c;
while (true) {
    c = getchar();
    if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    if (counter % VALUE < VALUE - 1) {
        num[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    } else {
        char* temp = (char*) malloc((counter + MAX_VALUE)*sizeof(char));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            temp[i] = num[i];
        }
        free(num);
        num = temp;
        num[counter] = c;
        counter++;
    }
}
printf("counter = %d\n",counter);
```

Comment: I tried `getchar` but got the same problem, can you show how to use it right?

Comment: @vesii How is `num` declared?

Comment: its `char*` (dynamic array of chars). what is `isspace`? can't I use `\n`?

Comment: @vesii `\n` only skips newline. `isspace` skips all spaces (tab, spacebar, carriage return, etc.)

Comment: by doing your way, there are still white spaces so after the the first break and when I call this function second time, it reads the newline instead the new input. what to do?

Comment: @vesii I don't know. I can't test your program because it doesn't have a `main` function or a declaration for `num`.